# How to change the codeigniter's URL using .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'd like to know how to do the URL rewriting using .htaccess file.
My web application is based on PHP CodeIgniter and I am going to implement the SEF function.

Current URL is

```
http://localhost/index.php/sale/list
```

In this URL, "sale" is a controller name and "list" is a method name.
I'd like to replace the URL with `http://localhost/index.php/product-sales/list`

I would think this can be done easily with .htaccess file if you know .htaccess well.

Thanks for your attention and time.
Regards,

Comment: Why not change your routing in the routes file. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: Hi Daniel, I know I can change it in routing. But there are already many old urls on db. So I'd like to solve this with .htacess file.

Comment: Do you want to redirect only 1 link or multiple based on some parameters?

Comment: Hi Mikeyhun, I'd like to change the controller's part. I think it is 1 link. e.g. sale/list, sale/update, sale/search?order_by=xxx, etc. The above urls should be replaced with product-sales/list, product-sales/udpate and product-sales/search?order_by.

Comment: There are many tutorials on this: https://wpscholar.com/blog/simple-redirects-with-htaccess/  ... But I wouldn't go in that direction but start typing away in your routing system. You only put more dirt in your app if you don't fix the thing where it should be fixed.

Comment: .htaccess is the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Put this into your .htaccess file and will rewrite everything that's index.php/sale/... to index.php/product-sales/...

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index\.php/sale/(.+)$ index.php/product-sales/$1 [R=301,L]
```

BUT I agree with @Daniel that it might be better to fix it in system rather than in htaccess

Edit: if i understand it right now, you just want to have a new url for the same controller so after you added the upper rule to your htaccess (so you redirect the old url's to the new one) you still need to add the new routes to the routes file like:

```
$route['product-sales/(:any)'] = 'sale/$1';
```

It should work now, if that's not the desired effect then explain more pls...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I couldn't get it solved. `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php/orders/(.+)$ index.php/product-sales/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} phppointofsale.com
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots_allow.txt

</IfModule>`

Comment: Additionally, I am running the Codeigniter on the local virtual host.@Mikeyhun

Comment: Wait! You still using the 'sale' controller and want to redirect everything from /sale/ and /product-sales/ to the 'sale' controller or you made a new controller? I'm a bit confused now (also that you wrote /orders/ to rewrite to 'product-sales'

Comment: sorry for confusing. But I think there is no difference between controller names orders and sale on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

All routing is defined in route.php file.

Navigate to your project.
Open application/config/routes.php file.

```
$route['sale/list'] = 'product-sales/list/';
```